# Model constraint on checking existing relationship between two fields

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a Django app and I want ***Users*** to be able to review ***Courses***.

The ***Users*** have to select the ***Professor*** they are reviewing when creating a ***Review***, because multiple ***Professor*** can teach that single ***Course***.

I created a ***Taught*** table that keeps the relations between ***Professors*** and ***Courses***.

How do I enforce that when I'm adding a review, I will only be shown in the dropdown of professors, the professors which have an existing relationship with that course (only the professors which have taught the course).

```
class Professor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    professor = models.ManyToManyField(Professor, through="Teaches", related_name='taughtBy')

class Teaches(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="reviews_course")
    professor=models.ForeignKey(Professor,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="reviews_professor") 


class Review(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="is_author")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="reviews_course")
    professor = <<<<How do I enforce that professor and course have to have an existing relationship in Teaches?>>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check operation in [m2m](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship.

```
course_object.professors.all()
#or
professor_object.course_set.all()
```

**EDIT**

```
from django import forms
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['professor'] = #insert the above data
```

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit please

Comment: Ok thanks for the edit. Where can I read more about django forms? I keep getting stuck on them and the doc about them is really not helpful enough. 

Also, what is course_object supposed to be? Of course I get "not initialized".

Comment: I know the documentation is overwhelming (especially at the beginning). As a supplement, see [Mozilla's materials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms) or video courses on YouTube. The course_object is a class object. You can find more information about forwarding [relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).